# Cannot boot OS X on Mac after installing Ubuntu

Tags: macos

I installed Ubuntu on my Mac however when I boot up it doesn't give me an option to boot to anything like it used to, now it just boots straight to Ubuntu. I am wondering how I can boot to my OS X

Comment: See if you can boot to Recovery, Cmd/R at boot. If so, check Disk Utility & make sure Ubuntu didn't just take the whole drive for itself.

Comment: I can do cmd/r should I let it run?

Comment: if it needs to 'run' for anything more than a minute or two without getting to recovery, then chances are it's going to internet recovery rather than the Recovery partition - which doesn't bode well. But yes, let it run, see what Disk Utility makes of it. My money, unfortunately, is on Ubuntu having taken the drive.

Comment: Under my 121.33 GB APPLE SSD SD0128F media I have two partitions, Macintosh HD and disk0s3. I don't think Ubuntu has taken the entire disk, I think what happened is Ubuntu is the only thing seen by the boot loader so it doesn't know it can boot from the other partition. That is just my guess but i have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: When starting up a the Mac computer, you can hold down the alt/option key. You usually get a menu of all available operating systems as determined by the firmware.  If OS X or the OS X recovery partition do not appear, then you probably have lost OS X on your computer. So, what happens when you try this?

Comment: Ok so I press the option key during start up and it only shows the Mac OS X and that boots to the OS X. It doesn't even show Ubuntu but if I don't do anything on start up it just goes to Ubuntu. I have no idea what is going on but I guess it sort of works

Comment: Fortunately, I do know what is wrong. BTW, you have to add a @David to your comment, otherwise I will not be notified you posted a message. I will have to add an answer later when I have time. Your boot problem can be solved by either rearranging the files in your EFI partition or installing a free copy of the rEFInd boot loader. Maybe someone else will beat me and post their own answer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Do you think that you might add your answer, now?